# Login and password on script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, login, password

I need your help to creat a script for my company , the script must execute a bin script by a command line, once it launches the command the service asks for a login and a password, after this step the script must continue its job of executing other commands.

I wanted to know how I can automate these steps with a script to mention the login and password requested by the service bin and continue doing the other commands

[cmd line of bin that asks for credentiels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Xnt.png)

Comment: This is the kind of thing that would traditionally be done using an [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) script

Comment: Hello , Thanks for you help , here is the script that i made but it doesnt work 
****************
cd /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/bin
./jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=127.0.0.1:9990
expect "username:"

send "$admin\r"
expect "password:"

send "$@123456dp@\r"
expect "%"

deploy /tmp/free.war